# What can I use on the document to apply a function from time to time including future elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have pieces of HTML that are added as the user clicks a button, and I want from time to time to make changes on the pieces that are being added. I can't use `$(document).ready()` because when the page is ready / loaded, those parts of the code are not there yet.

What can I use on the document to apply a function from time to time to the DOM including future elements? Something like:

```
$(document).atEach(3000, function() {
    // As the user clicks a button, a field is added to the page with a class.
    // The "window" applies every 3 seconds the given function within the scope of all the DOM,
    // (It updates the elements that were inserted)
    if ($(".class").val().length) {
        $(".class").removeClass("input-red").addClass("input-green");
    } else {
        $(".class").addClass("input-red").removeClass("input-green");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a function in regular time intervals you can use [`setInteval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```
setInterval(function() {
    // As the user clicks a button, a field is added to the page with a class.
    // The "window" applies every 3 seconds the given function within the scope of all the DOM,
    // (It updates the elements that were inserted)
    if ($(".class").val().length) {
        $(".class").removeClass("input-red").addClass("input-green");
    } else {
        $(".class").addClass("input-red").removeClass("input-green");
    }
}, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ma7p3hcr/1/

I'm not sure what your function is supposed to do but I guess it's some kind of input validation. If that's the case you should just listen to `oninput` event and execute it then. Event delegation makes it possible to listen to events on dynamically added inputs:

```
$(document).on('input', '.class', function(){
   if( $(this).val().length ){
        $(this).removeClass("input-red").addClass("input-green");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("input-red").removeClass("input-green");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnc84mhf/

Comment: Oh, I see! I just have to use setInterval() on "global scope". Thank you very much!

Comment: @EricsonWillians `setInterval` answers your question, but the other method probably solves the underlying problem ;)